# Reusing same ResultMap for two different queries in single fetch in mybatis

Tags: mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis

**Requirement:** I need to fetch partial data from two queries and populate the data into single resultmap.

**Problem:** When we get data from one query it is able to load the data into resultmap, but when I load the data from second query into the same result map the data is getting refreshed.

I guess it is creating a new map when we use same resultmap.Is there a way to make a resultmap available through out the session in `mapper.xml`.

**Code**

```
    public Details { 
      private Term term;
    }

    public Term {
       private String name;
       private String location;
    }
```

**`mapper.xml`**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
            <!DOCTYPE mapper
              PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
              "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
    <mapper namespace="org.project.example.MyMapper">
              <select id="select_form" parameterType="long" resultMap="select-result">
                    select id,name from details where id= #{id}
              </select>
              <select id="select_form_ext" parameterType="long" resultMap="select-result-ext">
                    select id,location from term where id= #{id}
               </select>
               <resultMap id="select-result" type="DetailsDto">
                        <association property="TermDto" column="ID"  select="select_form_ext"  />
                        <association property="TermDto" column="ID"  resultMap="select-main-result"  />
               </resultMap>                   
               <resultMap id="select-result-ext" type="TermDto">
                      <result property="location" column="LOCATION" />
               </resultMap>                      
               <resultMap id="select-main-result" type="TermDto" >
                       <result property="name" column="NAME" />
               </resultMap>
    </mapper>
```

Comment: What are your two different queries in Mybatis mapper.xml file.

Comment: Yes those two queries are in mapper.xml @mippy

Comment: And in one select?

Comment: Two different selects @Mippy

Comment: I'm not clear for your load data twice. Could you provide some code in your post?

Comment: You can just edit your question and add some code in it.

Comment: i have added the details in my answer @Mippy

Comment: Wow, why did you just add these details in your question please.

Comment: Yeah you are right @Mippy i have added in question.Please let me know your answer for this problem

Comment: @Mippy any luck ????

Comment: Try the below suggested answer and let me know if it works or !

Comment: i have tried it and I am always getting result for location and name as null @09Q71AO534

Answer (score 0):

Please give a try using the below steps.

**Step1#:** Remove the below line `<association property="TermDto" column="ID"  resultMap="select-main-result"  />` from `<resultMap id="select-result" >...`

**Step2#:** Modify the ResultMap`select-result-ext` as below

```
<resultMap id="select-result-ext" type="TermDto">
        <result property="location" column="LOCATION" />
        <result property="name" column="NAME" />
</resultMap>
```

**Step3#:** Execute/Run the application and check the Results.

**Eg#:**

```
<resultMap id="blogResult" type="Blog">
  <association property="author" column="author_id" javaType="Author" select="selectAuthor"/>
</resultMap>

<select id="selectBlog" resultMap="blogResult">
  SELECT * FROM BLOG WHERE ID = #{id}
</select>

<select id="selectAuthor" resultType="Author">
  SELECT * FROM AUTHOR WHERE ID = #{id}
</select>
```

Comment: yeah I have tried the option it only renders the value location and the property name is always null @09Q71A0534

Comment: Can you run your app in debug mode and check the Dynamic SQL Statement which was generated producing results or not

Comment: Check whether the column names were matched or not with the SQL Statement which is executed to the `column="NAME"` & `column="LOCATION"`

Comment: @KishoreKanumalla Did those suggestions helped you out fixing the problem ?

Comment: No sir I tried all the options it didn't worked out for me

Comment: hmm.. Can you please debug your code and edit the question with the queries which were generated at run-time.  It would be helpful to find the root cause of your problem. The above *Eg#* is working perfect in my machine.Possible can you copy paste the DTO objects as well...

Comment: Hi sir thanks for your help.I did workaround solution so currently I am not looking into this issue anymore